# How to split a text file based on common values in a column?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing in python and I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
chr9    6533147 6533150 NM_000170.2_cds_0_0_chr9_6533017_r
chr9    6533150 6533160 NM_000170.2_cds_0_0_chr9_6533017_r
chr9    6534707 6534708 NM_000170.2_cds_1_0_chr9_6534708_r
chr9    6534708 6534710 NM_000170.2_cds_1_0_chr9_6534708_r
```

How would I separate this file into multiple files, based on common values found in the 4th column (There are two different CDS in the example used)? So the resultant files would have the following in one file

```
chr9    6533147 6533150 NM_000170.2_cds_0_0_chr9_6533017_r
chr9    6533150 6533160 NM_000170.2_cds_0_0_chr9_6533017_r
```

And the following in a different file:

```
chr9    6534707 6534708 NM_000170.2_cds_1_0_chr9_6534708_r
chr9    6534708 6534710 NM_000170.2_cds_1_0_chr9_6534708_r
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to suggest when asking a question in **SO**, attach what you've already tried.

People are here to assist you improve your solutions or fix your mistakes, not to code solutions for you.

Now when it comes to your question.

There are multiple ways to achieve this in python, one of them can be using pandas.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

# Read the file from the the same path where the code is
# It will consider a space as the separator between entries
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',sep=" ",header=None)
# parse the entries of the column you want to a set to remove duplicates
unique_entries = set(df[3].to_list())

list_of_dfs = []
# Iterate and split the dataframes when they have the desired value
for i in unique_entries:
    df1 = df[df[3] == i]
    list_of_dfs.append(df1)

# Save the X new dfs into files
for index,df in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    print(index)
    df.to_csv("newFile{index}.txt".format(index=index),header=None,sep=" ",index=False)
```